# HostGator won't connect via cURL to an Amazon API

Tags: api, curl, amazon-cloudfront, servicem8

The following code executes no problem on 2 other servers I have access to and use to run on Hostgator.
Hostgator tech support refuse to help as they feel it's an issue with the code.
I get no response from the API unless I change the HTTPS to HTTP in which case I get a 307 redirect message from cloudfront.net.
Any ideas on what a solution might be?

```
$data = array(
  "status" => "Quote",
  "job_address" => "1 Infinite Loop, Cupertino, California 95014, United States",
  "job_description" => "Client has requested quote for service delivery"
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.servicem8.com/api_1.0/Job.json');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "xxx@xxxxx.com:password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE , true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json','Accept: application/json'));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($response);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my problem was fairly specific.  In short, I was running PHP5.4 on my Hostgator environment which was not allowing appropriate SSL handshakes to happen...
The solution was to upgrade to PHP 5.6